# My KNN result not as expected for all numerical data

Tags: r, data-imputation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have developed the following KNN code and tested it against several datasets with >90% accuracy (the wdbc dataset from UCI for one, granted it was a categorical result), however when using the same code with the pima Indians diabetes data set I get very poor results. I am trying to impute the BMI from the adjacent columns. I have removed the 0 values of the BMI and separated the data set into 70% train/30% test.  Then set up the BMI for labels etc.  My accuracy is 1% and I cannot understand why.  Somehow I have missed cleaning the data correctly but I cannot find where I am missing this. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code and a data sample is below that:

```
#new script to predict Pima Indians diabetes 
setwd("C:/Users/jbrow/Desktop/kaggle/pima")

#load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

#read in the csv file to a data frame
pima.full <- read.csv(file = "diabetes.csv", header = TRUE)

#we will use pima.work as the working data frame
#scale the data - necessary for the Euclidean distance to work 
  properly
#create a function to normalize data from 0 - 1

#remove all the BMI equal to 0 and select the columns with 
correlation to BMI
work.df <- pima.full %>% filter(BMI != 0) %>% select(2,3,4,5,6)

#create normalization functions
data_norm <- function(x){((x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}
data_denorm <- function(x){x*(max(x)-min(x))+min(x)}

pima.norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(work.df[,-5],data_norm))

#split the data set into training and testing
set.seed(123)

#number of training rows of the total data
sizedf <- floor(0.7 * nrow(pima.norm))

#get the row numbers
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(pima.norm)),size = sizedf)

#training data from four relevant normalized columns 
data_train <- pima.norm[train_ind,]
#testing data from same normalized columns
data_test <- pima.norm[-train_ind,]
#training labels - column 6 - BMI
train_labels <- work.df[train_ind,5]
#testing labels
test_labels <- work.df[-train_ind,5]

#model run
#install.packages('class')
library(class)

knn.BMI <- knn(train = data_train, 
              test = data_test, 
              cl=train_labels, 
              k=round(sqrt(nrow(data_train))))

# plotting results
con_mat = as.matrix(table(Actual = test_labels, Predicted = 
         knn.BMI))
knn_acc = sum(diag(con_mat))/length(train_labels)
```

I have tried the same code logic against other datasets with good results so I believe the issue lies with preparing the data. Kind of at a lost now.

Apologies that I cannot get the tables to print legibly but the data sets are from the pima indian set on Kaggle.

columns from work.df:   Glucose BloodPressure SkinThickness Insulin  BMI

columns (normalized) from pima.norm: Glucose BloodPressure SkinThickness   Insulin

Comment: Is BMI continuous or categorical? It doesn't really make sense to use accuracy to evaluate a continuous regression, since the likelihood of predicting a continuous value *exactly* correctly is 0. You may have an excellent predictor that estimates BMI to an arbitrary degree of precision, which could still technically have 0% accuracy if it always predicts too high/low by a billionth of a unit or some other arbitrarily small delta.

Comment: Thank you, the BMI data is continuous. You are correct in that examination of the data showed most values to be close but not exact.  That being said, perhaps a linear type regression analysis would yield satisfactory results.

Comment: Yes, that is a much better approach. With categorical target variables, you just care about whether you got it right or not - if the answer is Class 1, it doesn't really matter if you said it was Class 2 or Class 3, both are "equally wrong". With continuous target variables, *how much* you miss by is important - if the correct value is 8.2, a prediction of 8.3 is much better than a prediction of 8300, but accuracy again measures those as "equally wrong". Use something like RMSE to evaluate the magnitude of errors.